# Loess Spark/Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I was wondering if the LOESS (locally estimated scatterplot smoothing) regression was a function built-in Spark/PySpark (I'm more interested in the PySpark answer but both would be interesting).

I did some research and couldn't find one so decided to try and code it myself using pandas-udf functions but while doing it, when I displayed the scatter_plot of the manufactured data I created to begin testing my algo, Azure Databricks (on which I'm coding) proposed to me to automatically compute/display the LOESS of my dataset :

[image]

[image]

So maybe there is indeed a built-in LOESS that I just couldn't find ? If not (and Databricks is the only one responsible for this), is there any way to access the result of databricks's LOESS computation/access the function Databricks is using to do that ?

Thank you in advance :)